# Magento 2: Custom block in list.phtml

Tags: magento2, list.phtml

I have created a custom block in my module to show the quantity of each product in `list.phtml` file.
I modify in my custom template list.phtml with the code below

```
<?php
$myBlock= $block->getLayout()>createBlock('MyCompany\Helloworld\Block\Display');
echo $myBlock->getMyCustomMethod();
?>
```

but nothing appears and it also destroys the appearance. It only shows one product without any customization.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: add your block file as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to show the quantity of each product in list.phtml file -

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$myBlock =$objectManager->create('MyCompany\Helloworld\Block\Display');   
echo $myBlock->getMyCustomMethod();
```

Comment: Still nothing. My block does not appear and it ruins the appearance.